# Bash script to fill sqlite table not working as expected

Tags: bash, sqlite

I've created a Bash script to look through files within a directory, pull data based on an identifier then use that data to fill an sqlite3 table. It seems some information will fill into the same row as the key, and some won't. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 review.sql "CREATE TABLE Review(Review_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Author TEXT, Date TEXT);"

path="/home/me/Downloads/test/*"

for i in $path
do
        total=$(grep -c '<Author>' $i)
        count=1
        while [ $count -le $total ]
        do
                date=$(grep -m$count '<Date>' $i | sed 's#<Date>##' | tail -n1)
                author=$(grep -m$count '<Author>' $i | sed 's#<Author>##' | tail -n1)
                sqlite3 review.sql "INSERT INTO Review(Author,Date) VALUES('$author','$date');"
                ((count++))
        done
done
```

The Files I'm look through look like this:

```
<Author>john
<Date>Jan 6, 2009

<Author>jacob
<Date>Dec 26, 2008

<Author>rachael
<Date>Dec 14, 2008
```

when I query for the primary key and the date attributes i get this as expected

```
sqlite> SELECT Review_ID, Date FROM Review;
Review_ID   Date        
----------  ------------
1           Jan 6, 2009
2           Dec 26, 2008
3           Dec 14, 2008
4           Jan 7, 2009
5           Jan 5, 2009
6           Nov 14, 2008
```

but when i query for the primary key and author i get this

```
sqlite> SELECT Review_ID, Author FROM Review;
Review_ID   Author    
----------  ----------
            john
            jacob
            rachael
            Jean
            kareem
            may
```

Upon doing some more testing, it definitely seems to have problems with some of the text string. For example I tried adding last names, and get this result:

```
Review_ID   Author
----------  ------------
1            john jacob
2            jacob richa
             rae simon
             Jean jak
5            kareem jabr
6            may flower
```

It does better, but still doesn't like a couple of them, i thought maybe something to do with three letters, but then "may" wouldn't be showing up, but indeed if I add a letter to "rae" and a letter to "jak" the 3 and 4 do actually show up in the Review_ID column. I noticed the same thing happens if a column contains a "$", like in "$173" for example. The text, I really can't figure out though, there doesn't seem to be an obvious absolute pattern to what it accepts and what it doesn't. I made up the names in order to simplify this post, but just to give a few more examples I'll include a some more examples from what I'm actually working with to show a few more strings that work and ones that don't.

```
1           everywhereman2
            RW53  
            Marilyn1949
            fallriverma
8           SweetwaterMill
            AuntSusie006
13          Traveler34NewJe
            madmatriarch
 2          Savvytourist2
            greatvictory
25          Lightsleeper999
            strollaround
30          Lucygoosey1985
            lesbriggs
 3          miguelluna019
            lulubaby
 1          myassesdragon
            tomu023
            BrettOcean
46          A TripAdvisor M
            dmills1956
            julcarl
49          A TripAdvisor M
            TSW42
            lass=
```

Answer (score 0):

After a dry run, remove the `echo` to take the safety off.

```sh
awk -v RS='' -v FS='\n?<[^>]+>' '{print $2 ":" $3}' \
    /home/me/Downloads/test/* |while IFS=: read author date; do
      echo sqlite review.sql "INSERT INTO Review(Author,Date) VALUES('$author','$date');"
    done
```

This is a brittle awk-to-bash solution based on using the regular expression `\n?<[^>]+>` as Field Separator and a blank line `''` as Record Separator. The FS expression means "optional newline followed by a string enclosed by angles." We then output the fields with a simple separator `:` and read them into bash.

You can make system calls in awk with `system()`, but it gets very messy very quickly. Better to export the clean data in this case.

Comment: with this it seems to only be picking up on the first instances in each file, though it might just be stopping at the blank line. It still seems to give a weird output as well,  for author it has a blank line every other row and skips every other key. and for date it only fills in for every other key.

Comment: Would you please show a sample of the results of the dry run?

Comment: I've nearly found a different solution. It seems everything works fine if there are 13 characters or more in the string, I found this out by editing the file itself. My solution would be to input something like:  -     (name)      -.  I'm trying to add these characters with awk and printf, and I've tried just concatenating the strings, but neither solution is working quite as expected. I'll post the script as an answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

The script with awk and printf is:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 review.sql "CREATE TABLE Review(Review_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Author TEXT, Date TEXT);"

path="/home/drew/Downloads/testcases/*"

for i in $path
do
        total=$(grep -c '<Author>' $i)
        count=1
        while [ $count -le $total ]
        do
                date=$(grep -m$count '<Date>' $i | sed 's#<Date>##' | tail -n1)
                author=$(grep -m$count '<Author>' $i | sed 's#<Author>##' | tail -n1 | awk '{printf "-      %s      -", $1}')
                echo $author
                ((count++))
        done
done
```

I'm not sure, but I feel like I shouldn't have to add echo to it with printf, but without it nothing prints. With the echo I get the following output:

```
 -Jeanjakey
- kareem -
- may -
- RW53 -
 -Marilyn1949
 -AuntSusie006
 -madmatriarch
 -strollaround
 -lulubaby
 -tomu023
 -julcarl
 -slass
```

It seems to somewhat work, but the spacing disappears, any last names disappear, and it seems to do different things to different inputs. With the string concatenation I use the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 review.sql "CREATE TABLE Review(Review_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Author TEXT, Date TEXT);"


path="/home/drew/Downloads/testcases/*"

for i in $path
do
        total=$(grep -c '<Author>' $i)
        count=1
        while [ $count -le $total ]
        do
                date=$(grep -m$count '<Date>' $i | sed 's#<Date>##' | tail -n1)
                author2="-   "
                author2+=$(grep -m$count '<Author>' $i | sed 's#<Author>##' | tail -n1)
                author2+="    -"
                echo $author
                ((count++))
        done
done
```

with this I get the output:

```
 -Jeanjakey
 -kareem jabron
 -may flow she
 -RW53 
 -Marilyn1949
 -AuntSusie006
 -madmatriarch
 -strollaround
 -lulubaby
 -tomu023
 -julcarl
 -slass
```

and a string reassignment:

```
author2=$(grep -m$count '<Author>' $i | sed 's#<Author>##' | tail -n1)
author2="-   $author2     - "
```

gives the same output.